# What are the ways in which Greek print might indicate diaeresis?

Tags: ancient-greek, scansion, diphthong, diacritics

When two vowel letters that normally form a diphthong, such as αι, are meant to be pronounced as two syllables, how is this normally indicated in modern printing of Ancient Greek?

Is a trema ever used, as in e.g. Latin *aër*? I think I have seen this in Greek as well, but I am unsure now.

When there is no trema, but a diacritic was placed on the first letter, is that a clear indication that it is no diphthong? Example from the Odyssey:

[image]

Here I believe the metre indicates diaeresis, or I wouldn't know how to scan the verse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option, as you say, is putting a diacritic on the first vowel. Since diacritics are always put on the *second* vowel of a diphthong, and breathings are always put on the first vowel of a word, αἰ must be one syllable, and ἀι must be two.

But sometimes the not-a-diphthong isn't conveniently at the start of a word, and doesn't have the ictus on the first element. In this case, the diaeresis is used. Here's *Iliad* I.3 in the Chicago Homer edition:

[image: a line of Homer showing diaereses in Ἄϊδι προΐαψεν]

And in the Loeb:

[image: the same line in another edition]

Both of these use the diaeresis even when the breathing and accent should be sufficient, like in Ἄϊδι; this isn't universal, but is convenient. I haven't dealt with any editions that *don't* use the diaeresis on words like προΐαψεν, especially in poetry, but there are probably some out there in the world.

Skimming through the *Odyssey*, there should be a diaeresis in δαΐφρονι in I.48. Does your edition have that one? Or does it leave it to the reader's scansion skills? (If you don't have book I in that edition, I can find another instance; the *Odyssey* has fewer of these than the *Iliad* but there should still be a handful around.)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! The photo is from an edition that we have lying around at school: I will consult it again on Tuesday. Another example, Odyssey I.99: εἵλετο δ᾽ ἄλκιμον ἔγχος, ἀκαχμένον ὀξέι χαλκῷ, from the Perseus text. It does have one on δαΐφρονι, or you wouldn't be able to tell in any other way, as you said.

Comment: *doesn't have the ictus on the first element* -- do you mean "accent"?

Comment: @TKR Yes, but I've heard ictus used specifically for the thing that falls on a certain mora, as opposed to the accent which falls on a certain syllable.

Comment: @Cerberus On δαΐφρονι, I mean—the places where it's needed to avoid ambiguity. Edited to make that clear.

Comment: @Draconis: Clear now!